# Javadoc generation failed when I try to run React Native on Android Emulator

Tags: android, react-native

```sh
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rn-indy-sdk:androidJavadoc'.
> Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): '/Users/.../MyProject/node_modules/rn-indy-sdk/android/build/tmp/androidJavadoc/javadoc.options'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3m 58s
2306 actionable tasks: 2107 executed, 199 up-to-date
error Failed to build the app.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew build -x lint
    at makeError (/Users/.../MyProject/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (/Users/.../MyProject/node_modules/execa/index.js:338:15)
    at buildApk (/Users/.../MyProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:181:22)
    at runOnSpecificDevice (/Users/.../MyProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:162:7)
    at buildAndRun (/Users/.../MyProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:147:12)
    at /Users/.../MyProject/ItdotMobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:132:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/.../MyProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

When I run `yarn run android` on a terminal, the build is failed for task `...androidJavadoc`.

`rn-indy-sdk` is a library that I use in my project, so it seems that `rn-indy-sdk` library cannot be built because of something related to Javadoc.

Where should I start to look at for solving this problem? Thanks.

Comment: can you share full screenshot for this error ( send terminal screenshot )

Comment: @KathirpandianK I added full logs from the terminal! :)

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem while using a different react native library. The solution is to open the build.gradle file located at `node_modules/rn-indy-sdk/android/build.gradle` and add this code:

```
tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
  failOnError false
  options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
  options.addStringOption('encoding', 'UTF-8')
  options.addStringOption('charSet', 'UTF-8')
}
```